# OpenFileDialog throws "Attempted to read or write protected memory"

Tags: vb.net, access-violation, openfiledialog

I face this error when I'm trying to browse files using OpenFileDialog1 in vb.net

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

I'm using this code:

```
    Try
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "(*.jpg)|*.jpg"
        OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Nothing
        OpenFileDialog1.FileName = ""
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        If OpenFileDialog1.FileName > "" Then
            TextBox8.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(TextBox8.Text)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
```

Everything works fine on my machine, but this error apears when run the app on the client machine!
Any ideas please?

Comment: I say the client should try repairing the .NET Framework version that your app is targeting. Also, not related to your issue, but this is not valid: `If OpenFileDialog1.FileName > "" Then` - you can't do math checks on a string. Check for: `If OpenFileDialog1.FileName.Length > 0 Then` instead.

Comment: Do you know which line is throwing the exception ?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? (ie change ex.Mesage to ex.ToString() in the MsgBox to get the full stack).

Comment: @VisualVincent or `OpenFileDialog1.FileName <> ""`, maybe a typo ?

Comment: the app is targeting .Net framework 3.5 that the default of windows 7

Comment: @MartinVerjans : Either or, both work fine. But if one is fussy the method I mentioned is actually faster if the app is compiled with "Optimize code". :)

Comment: Have you tried this on any other computer? Have the client repair his .NET 3.5 Framework. It might help.

Comment: @VisualVincent : i tried that on 5 different computers, this error only on one computer, all of them have windows 7 32/64bit with .Net 3.5

Comment: Then it is not your app's fault, it's a problem with that computer. _Repair .NET 3.5!_ -- Is your app a 32-bit app or AnyCPU?

Comment: @VisualVincent: `If OpenFileDialog1.FileName > "" Then` is actually [valid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cey92b0t.aspx)  See `Comparing Strings` about halfway down.

Comment: @VisualVincent: it's x86

Comment: @MrGadget : Oh, I wasn't aware of that! Thanks! -- Ayden : Ok, just wanted to know.

Comment: Code works fine, I've just tested. I don't like the use of `OpenFileDialog1.FileName > ""` and would change to what @VisualVincent suggested `If OpenFileDialog1.FileName.Length > 0` but that's personal preference. Repair .NET as suggested and see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue,
Just clean all solution project then rebuild.

Comment: No buddy, this is not the answer

Answer (score 0):

Finally i just find it out!
I was using ms Access 2010 with my projrct.
Solution: is to convert to use 2003!!!!
I don't know what is that related!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with this exception, there are highly two reasons for this issue:

1. This is the highly cause for your problem: always check your build platform targeting to match the assemblies you are calling, so it's a mixed platform issue as I think.
2. Always put the disposable components in the designer, or declare it as a private variable so it get's disposed with the form destructor called.

You can set the build option to set your target platform in the project settings dialog.